# Obtain r,g,b a -float values from Android Color Picker

Tags: android, color-picker, rgba

I'am using an Android Color Picker in my application which returns an android integer constant(-ve value). How can obtain r,g,b,a float values from the integer constant, so that I can pass r,g,b,a float values to opengl to update color.

Thanks

Comment: You can get R, G, B and A integers using e.g. int blue = Color.blue(RGBA_int). It'll be an integer between [0, 255] so divide it by 255f and you'll get a float [0f, 1f].

Comment: Thanks..new to Android!..worked perfectly:)

Answer (score 0):

Given an integer `myColor` that represents a color in Android, you can get the values (which will usually range from 0-255 depending on your color space) using the following:

```
int alpha = Color.alpha(myColor);
int red = Color.red(myColor);
int green = Color.green(myColor);
int blue = Color.blue(myColor);
```

If you're using API 26+, then you can also have these return as floats instead. E.g.:

```
float alpha = Color.alpha(myColor);
float red = Color.red(myColor);
float green = Color.green(myColor);
float blue = Color.blue(myColor);
```

If you desire to normalize these values (not needed for typical Android development, but may be needed by openGL), simply divide by `255f` or (if using a non-typical color space) by `getMaxValue(int componentIndex)`, where `componentIndex` is the index of that component (e.g. blue) in its color space definition.